# Android- How to implement a "Like" button in ActionBar

Tags: android, checkbox, android-actionbar

I have to implement a "Like" button in the `ActionBar` of my `Activity`. I saw that Android does not support a `CheckBox` for a `MenuItem` and would have to change the icon manually. I'm trying to do it, but the picture doesn't change using `setIcon`.

Could anyone help me?

here is my XML:

```
<item android:id="@+id/action_good"
        android:title="@string/action_good"
        android:icon="@drawable/like"

        android:orderInCategory="100"
        app:showAsAction="ifRoom" />
```

And here is my code:

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {


        switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.action_good:
               //Handle the action
                item.setIcon(R.drawable.like_selected);
                break:
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use custom view instead of simple icon.
You can set menu icon in onCreateOptionsMenu() only. So, if you don't wont implement custom view, you need to call invalidateOptionsMenu() all the time, to re-create all menu.

Comment: And put a Checkbox inside of the custom view?

Comment: Yes, I think checkbox can be used, too. I tried ImageViews and ProgressBar only inside it.